# Razzle doesn't start server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, razzle

My react project is created using Razzle.js and I recently downloaded it from a repo.
I am trying to run this project, but if I `yarn start`, I'm stuck in this screen - it shows me the source is compiled and the server is running on `localhost:3000`, but it doesn't start the server.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razzle was supposed to enable Server-side HMR.
But my code was not enabling it and stuck in the screenshot.

Found a solution here -
Linux has the max_user_watches limited, increase it by:

`echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

[SOURCE](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/issues/957#issuecomment-480482045)